# Problems with audio (audio popping / crackling) and Wi-Fi

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio, galaxy

I have a problem with Galaxy s8 and my app,
the music in the game has some popping sounds/crackling, I tried everything- re-importing the files to *.OGG, changing the bitrate, compression settings, audio settings, nothing worked.

In the end, I found a post that solved the issue- when you disable the Wi-Fi on Galaxy S8, the music suddenly becomes fine. And it worked, but it's obviously not a solution.

But it's definitely Unity issue, because other games f(or example candy crush) on my phone don't have any problems with the music, just my unity apps.

My unity version is 2019.2.18f1

Comment: Maybe try upgrading to the latest Unity version and see if they fixed this issue. Sounds like a hardware/firmware related issue that you probably can't solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well having **worked** for AT&T and Sprint when we had issues with apps not working on handheld devices we would advise the customer to save everything back ups phone numbers and pics then perform a bios factory reset. Most always phones work as they should. I hope this method has helped or will help mate. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks but I can't tell my thousand of users who play my app to do a bios factory reset

Comment: It seems to be a hardware related issue then, if you have already debugged the app and modified assets. Maybe you have found a bug on that particular android device. I have unity games running on multiple devices  and they don't run into that issue. or your app is not optimized to run with that particular handheld device. Sometimes a specific configuration can bring disaster.

Comment: If you google this issue- you can see that many people have this problem after upgrading to Pie on Galaxy s8... but when I download some other games on my device they don't have that problem, they somehow solved it in their app SOFTWARE. And that brings me to my question, hopefully, someone can answer. I can also confirm that Galaxy S6 doesn't have that problem